# Gazebo Ground truth pose

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble, nav2

I'm currently running a simulation with multiple robots on gazebo fortress and I was wondering how I could have gazebo publishing the ground truth pose of each robot in a way that can be used with Nav2

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mechaick, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.